# How do I get an Enter USB TV Box TV tuner aka Gadmei UTV302 to work?

Tags: 10.10, usb, tv

Has anyone had any success in using the Enter USB TV Box from Enter Multimedia? It comes bundled with software that works in Windows. I have had no luck using it in Ubuntu 10.10.

**Update 1**
Here is the output from lsusb

```
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 046d:c312 Logitech, Inc. DeLuxe 250 Keyboard
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 1f71:3301
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I can't find the Enter USB TV Box listed in this.

In the dmesg tail command, I found something that seems to be related to the card:

```
usb 1-5: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 6
usb 1-5: config 1 interface 0 altsetting 1 bulk endpoint 0x83 has invalid maxpacket 256
```

**Update 2**
From Windows I learned that this USB TV tuner uses some chipset from Gadmei corporation. All computer stores in India sell Enter USB TV Box if you ask for an USB TV tuner. No other brand seems to be interested in this market.

**Update 3**
I learned that this TV tuner is rebranded version of [Gadmei UTV302 (USB TV Tuner Box)](http://www.gadmei.com/en/product_show.aspx?id=76).

**Update 4**
I tried adding em28xx as the chipset (as suggested by user BOBBO below) for the tuner but that did not work. I went back to my Pinnacle PCTV internal card. I don't think the tuner referred by UbuntuForums (Gadmei UTV 330) and the tuner that I have (Gadmei UTV 302) are the same. My USB tuner is several times bigger. My tuner seems to be a newer device with a newer tuner chip. I will submit details of this device to the LinuxTV developers this weekend.

**Update 5**
I opened the tuner box and found that it uses a tuner from a Chinese company - Tenas. Model is TNF 8022-DFA.

[image: Circuit board of Gadmei UTV302 TV tuner showing Tenas TNF 8022-DFA tuner chip]

**Update 6**
Tuner chip specs (retrived from [supplier directory](http://tena.manufacturer.globalsources.com/si/6008841553616/pdtl/Tuner-module/1040716858/FS-Tuner.htm)) for Tenas TNF 8022-DFA.

> - Supply voltage: true 5V device(low power dissipation)
> - Control system: I2C bus control of tuning, address selection
> - Tuning system: PLL controlled tuning
> - Receiving system: system PAL D/K,IF(Intermediate Frequency): 38MHz
> - Receiving channels: full frequency range from channel DS1 (49.75MHz) to channel DS57 (863.25MHz);
> - Use [Texas Instruments SN761678 IC solution](http://www.ti.com/product/sn761678), with mini install size

**Update 7**

1. [Reverse side of the circuit board.](http://bayimg.com/mAnaEaAdg)
2. [Picture of the TV tuner](http://bayimg.com/MaNaBAADg)

Comment: Most of these USB DVB devices share common chipsets. Could you please plug it and edit your post to include the output of `lsusb`? That way we can see what the hardware actually is. Chances are you'll be able to use it with native software like MeTV, etc.

Comment: Quite often you'll need to compile the modules direct from linuxtv.org, because many of them aren't in the mainline kernel yet...

Comment: I have followed all the steps mentioned at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DVB-T_(USB). There were some errors in compilation but it would not work.

Answer (score 2):

**This contains instructions for compiling from source, and is for a different model. this *could* cause problems with future updates breaking the compatibility of these instructions**

1. Unplug the card from your PC (if you have already plugged it )
2. To run V4L (Video4Linux) Driver in system, you need following packages, make sure you add them through your Synaptic Package Manager.

   > mercurial
   >
   > gcc
   >
   > build-essential
   >
   > linux-source

AND

type following to download and install your linux headers which is compatible with your kernel

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

1. You must get a copy of the V4L (Video4Linux) Driver to do so tap the following code in a terminal

> $ mkdir tvdrviver
>
> $ cd tvdriver
>
> $ hg clone http://mcentral.de/hg/~mrec/v4l-dvb-kernel

above commands will download a copy of V4l Driver into your tvdriver folder.

1. Now we have to build the V4L driver and install it into the kernel. to so take following lines in your terminal window.

   > $ cd v4l-dvb-kernel
   >
   > $ make
   >
   > $ sudo make install`

if every thing goes good it will install the driver in few mins without any errors.

At this point your must REBOOT your box (b4 you do so remeber to book mark this page )

1. You have installed your driver, now it's time to load the Driver. Before we do that I have to tell you this is where my problem was, coz the Driver couldn't detect my device automatically

so until it can't detect the device it will not give you /dev/video0

so what we have to do is we have to do detecting part manually. how we do it..? this is how.

The em28xx accepts the parameter 'card=' when it's loading,  is where you have to mention your device number from the driver device list. so my device is listed on 37th location in the list
So I'll load my device in to the driver as follows

**Reference**
 Check out: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=646528 . 
The instructions are for a different model (UTV 330)

Comment: This link is behind a login, unfortunately :( Whilst it may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Thanks :)

Comment: I tried adding em28xx as the chipset for the tuner but it wouldn't accept. I went back to my Pinnacle PCTV internal card. I don't think the Gadmei tuner (Gadmei UTV 330) referred on Ubuntu Forums and the Gadmei tuner (Gadmei UTV 302) that I have are the same. My USB tuner is several times bigger. My tuner seems to be a newer device with a newer tuner chip. I will submit details of this device to the LinuxTV developers this weekend.